# On imaginary time

Tags: reference-request, general-relativity

I've heard a few times that "the time was imaginary before the Big Bang".
I am guessing it means that at this stage, the space-time was a Riemannian $4$-manifold, but I am not sure this guess is correct.

If this is right, then I would like to know more about this Riemannian manifold.
But where a mathematician can learn about it?
Is there by any chance a book adapted to geometers? (otherwise it will be very hard to read.)

Comment: Could you provide some references about the "imaginary time"? And what does the word "before" mean when it describes the relationship between two events, one within imaginary time and the other real?

Comment: @LeechLattice --- this is indeed the key problem with the "imaginary time" device: The paper I cite in my answer formulates the paradoxical situation via a question: _"If some real time $t_r$ is later than some imaginary time $t_i$, then is $t_r$ later than $t_i$ in real time or in imaginary time?"_ There is no consistent answer to this question.

Answer (score 12):

The introduction of imaginary time as a way to resolve the Big Bang singularity is a [proposal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_time#In_cosmology) by Hawking and others. I don't think it plays a role in modern cosmology, see [Emerging from imaginary time.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00413497) The main difficulty is how to join the 4-dimensional region with Euclidean metric to a 3+1 dimensional space-time region with a Lorentzian metric.

The modern understanding is that time is *emergent*, not "imaginary". [Loop-quantum-gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity) is one theory that attempts to formalize this. It is not formulated starting from a metric on space-time, the very existence of three space dimensions and one time dimension is derived from a more fundamental framework.

Thinking of time as an emergent property is a bit like how we think of temperature. The fundamental theory of gas at the molecular level does not have temperature as a variable. This variable arises ("emerges") when one tries to describe the statistical properties of many molecules. In this sense time did not exist at the Big Bang singularity. It emerged as the universe developed.

Comment: There should be a metric with mixed signature that models the Big Bang. Do you know such examples?

Comment: something along these lines? https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.10669

Comment: I thought an explicit solution should be known, say for rotationally symmetric case.

Comment: I don't posit this answer suggests "imaginary" time to be at odds with reality (paragraph 2 sentence 1)? An imaginary-valued quantity in a valid model of time would interpret physically.

Comment: But how can time be truly emergent, i.e. what does it mean to describe things from a _timeless_ perspective? To me, that means the base mathematical structure used to derive physics would have to _not_ be a dynamical system, but you can derive structures isomorphic to dynamical systems from it. Is this how it works? Loop quantum gravity still seems to have the notion of a spacetime, just with geometric quantization with a quantum of area or volume, and the "spin network" still requires an embedding manifold. That said I haven't _deeply_ explored LQG so that could all be wet.

Comment: Also, what would be, regardless of a specific program like LQG, the reason to assume that at a fundamental scale, the very idea of dynamics and/or causality itself fails in favor of some atemporal, adynamical and/or acausal system? The fact that RQFT - a theory that already is on shaky ground inherently (Haag's theorem, Landau poles, the inability to infer the existence of hydrogen without making extra assumptions, etc.) - doesn't play well with GR does not, by itself, seem like it _inherently_ would imply atemporal/acausal systems are required to resolve it.

Comment: This is not an accurate answer. The Hawking no boundary proposal uses the Euclidean path integral to define a vector in a Hilbert space (for suitably physicsy meanings of the word ‘define’). I would also not say that the modern understanding of time is that it is emergent. Certainly people have made speculations in that direction, and certainly there are theories in which *spacetime* is emergent, but calling it thr “modern understanding” goes much too far.